# Is this a timestamp error in the Bitstamp api?

Tags: api, bitcoin

I am trying to find out the transactions in bitcoins using the Bitstamp API and the time stamp seems to be wrong as it shows transactions in milliseconds (Unix timestamp) from 1970(Jan 19 1970 precisely). Am i missing something or is it a mistake from their side?

API Link : https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/transactions/btcusd/
API Documentation : https://www.bitstamp.net/api/

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tested their **API** and it seems to be right.

[image]

They use UNIX Timestamp in the 'date' field. You can use a convertor (https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) to check the date in the format we're used to, like:
[image]